# How do boot ubuntu 22.04 LTS without using nomodeset?

Tags: boot

I am a complete noob to linux. This is a fresh install of ubuntu 22.04 LTS. I cannot get past a black screen unless using nomodeset. If I use nomodeset, the resolution in ubuntu is fixed and is impossible to look at.

I have a AMD radeon 5700xt GPU.

I tried to follow the answers of other people who had similar issues online but none of the solutions work. I have been trying to fix this for the past week. I do know however that my CPU has booted ubuntu version 20.something roughly a year ago with no issues.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: It would help if you're specific.  I gather you're talking about Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop (*and not Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server*), but you mention Ubuntu 20.*something* working without being specific; if that was Ubuntu 20.04(.5) LTS using the HWE kernel then I'd expect 22.04 LTS to also run as both 20.04.5 (using HWE) & 22.04(.1) using the GA kernel stack are using the same kernel.  Being specific on what you tried also help us understand your issue. The option of `nomodeset` uses a limited fallback module which yes has limitations.

Comment: I have tried multiple other kernel options such as fastboot/modeset=0/etc. None of them gets me past the black screen. I've also read online that it could be a graphics driver issue but ubuntu tells me all the drivers are up to date. 

Apparently my GPU is not supported by the 22.04 LTS version? Am I just forced to use ubuntu with nomodeset?